# How to logout user from BigCommerce Store, If user is already logged out from eshop developed in NextJS

Tags: next.js, bigcommerce, bigcommerce-stencil-cli

I'm using this [api](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/storefront/customer-login-api) to login user from our eshop web application developed in NextJS to BigCommerce store to navigate user on BigCommerce Native Checkout page.

My scenario is, if user some how logged out from our eshop but still having session on bigcommerce store how i can logout user from big commerce before navigating to checkout page as a guest.

```
const logoutUrl = `{store}/login.php?action=logout`;
const logoutWindow = window.open(logoutUrl, '_blank');
const checkLogout = setInterval(() => {
    logoutWindow?.close();
    clearInterval(checkLogout);
    router.push('/checkout');
}, 3000);
```

I tried this but in my opinion it's not a good approach.
So, How i can logged out user from bigcommerce before navigating to checkout page as a guest from my eshop web application?